# Biblatex: Part before volume

Tags: biblatex

I need to cite volumes of classic philosophers' complete works, which often come divided in several sections (or parts) each including several volumes.
Here is a correctly formatted example:

Wolff, Christian von (1962). *Philosophia prima sive Ontologia*. Ed. by
Jean Ecole. *Gesammelte Werke*. Abteilung 2: Lateinische Schriften, Bd. 3. Hildesheim: Olms.

I cannot figure out how to instruct biblatex to produce this output. I tried using the "part" and "volume" fields as in the ref below:

```
@Book{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Part                     = {Abt. 2: Lateinische Schriften},
  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Volume                   = {3},
  Language                 = {german}
}
```

Unfortunately,  biblatex seems to think that part is subordinated to volume, and produces a very different output. Moreover, the maintitle is printed before the book title. I would also like to have localized (German)  abbreviation for Part and Volume for entries like this one (the document language is English), and I though the language tag would take care of it, but apparently not. Here is the output:

Wolff, Christian von (1962). *Gesammelte Werke*. Vol. 3.2: Lateinische
Schriften: *Philosophia prima sive Ontologia*. Ed. by Jean Ecole.
Hildesheim: Olms.

Suggestions appreciated.

Edit: MWE with Latex and (included) bib ref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, indexing=cite, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Year                     = {1962},

  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Language                 = {German},
  Volume                   = {3},

  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Owner                    = {stefano},
  Part                     = {2: Lateinische Schriften}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
A citation of a multi-part work: \cite{Wolff1962}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Final edit: modified MWE incorporating and slightly modifying Carols's solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, indexing=cite, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, indexing=cite,autolang=other,language=autobib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BookInGesamm{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Year                     = {1962},    
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  langid                   = {german},
  Volume                   = {3},

  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Part                     = {2: Lateinische Schriften}
}

@Inbook{Pogliano2011,
  Title                    = {At the Periphery of the Rising Empire: The Case of Italy (1945-1968)},
  Author                   = {Claudio Pogliano},
  Editor                   = {Stefano Franchi and Francesco Bianchini},
  Pages                    = {119-147},
  Publisher                = {Rodopi},
  Year                     = {2011},   
  Address                  = {Amsterdam},    
  Booktitle                = {The Search for a Theory of Cognition: Early Mechanisms and New Ideas}
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[BookInGesamm]{title}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{bookingesamm}{%
   \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
   \usebibmacro{begentry}%
   \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   %\printlist{language}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printfield{edition}%
   \newunit
   \iffieldundef{maintitle}
     {\printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}}
     {}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{volumes}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{series+number}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printfield{note}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
     {\printfield{isbn}}
     {}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
   \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{pageref}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:related}
     {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
      \usebibmacro{related}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{finentry}}


 \newbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
   \iffieldundef{maintitle}
     {}
     {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \iffieldundef{volume}
        {}
        {\printfield[default]{part}%
         \setunit{\addcomma\space}
        \printfield{volume}}}%
   \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
   \newunit}

 \begin{document}
     A citation of a multi-part work: \cite{Wolff1962} and a citation of a real inbook ref: \cite{Pogliano2011}
    \printbibliography
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please, post a MWE. What style are you using? I think is authoryear.

Comment: @CarlosLanziano: I added a MWE.The style is indeed authoryear (or authoryear-ibid, to be precise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is better that you use `inbook`. For use other language in a entry in the bibliography is necessary add to entry the  `langid` and in the bibltex options put `autolang=other` and `language=autobib`.

I modified the `inbook` for get the order that you need. But you can modify the `book` driver if you think that is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{wolff.bib}
@inBook{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Part                     = {Abt. 2: Lateinische Schriften},
  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Volume                   = {3},
  langid                   = {german}
}
\end{filecontents}
 \usepackage[german,english]{babel}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, indexing=cite, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, indexing=cite,autolang=other,language=autobib]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{wolff.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  %\printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\newbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield[default]{part}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}
       \printfield{volume}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}
\cite{Wolff1962}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

It's possible that the final edit give a problem, because in my above answer was redefined the `maintitle+booktitle` macro (The answer has a mistake is better use `\renewbibmacro` and not `\newbibmacro` because the macro is already defined) and the `maintitle+booktitle` macro  is used with `incollection` and `inprocedings` too. Then the changes affect the others drivers (it means the order in the `volume` and `part` fields).

You can use the `inbook` with the `german` and other languages at the same time. Only is necessary add a logical that if the `langid` is `german`: do some `macro`, else: do another `macro`. Below a MWE with two `inbook` entry. A in `german` the other in `english`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{wolff.bib}
@inBook{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Part                     = {Abt. 2: Lateinische Schriften},
  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Volume                   = {3},
  langid                   = {german}
}

@inBook{other1999,
  Title                    = {The title in english},
  Author                   = {Last, Name},
  Editor                   = {Editor Name},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Address                  = {New York},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Part                     = {1},
  Maintitle                = {The Maintitle},
  Volume                   = {3},
}

\end{filecontents}
 \usepackage[german,english]{babel}
 \usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true, indexing=cite, citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authoryear-ibid, sorting=nyt, indexing=cite,autolang=other,language=autobib]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{wolff.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{%
\iffieldequalstr{langid}{german}{\mkbibemph{#1}}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{inbookgerman}{%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle/german}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printlist{language}%
}

\newbibmacro*{inbookother}{%
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
}

\newbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle/german}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \iffieldundef{volume}
       {}
       {\printfield[default]{part}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}
       \printfield{volume}}}%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldequalstr{langid}{german}{\usebibmacro{inbookgerman}}{\usebibmacro{inbookother}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{document}
\cite{Wolff1962}
\cite{other1999}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info on proper language settings. Works as a charm. As for the main issue, though, I cannot use your solution as is: if I tinker with the inbook driver as you suggested, biblatex will screw up all the other *true* inbook refs (of which I have many). However, it works like a charm if I just create a new bibtex type (say: BookInGesamm) and a related driver. Thanks!

Comment: For an alternative tot create a new bibtex type have a look at this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195910/16895. You can use a guard/conditional to limit modification to a single entry. I

Comment: @Guido: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know biblatex could be that flexible. In my case, I think it's better to create a new entry type, as I have several entries with the same problem I mentioned (it can't be helped, in my line of work). But I can see the usefulness of your approach and I'm sure it'll be handy in the future.

Comment: Another alternative is to add a field that signal that the entry is somehow special, and then to use a conditional checking that that special field is not empty.