# Swap Volume and Year for Articles and Separate Them With a Semicolon

Tags: biblatex

I have some problem in customizing bibliography style of @article using biblatex and biber when writing my paper. The picture shows the bibliography style generated by running .tex file. [image: Refstyle]

However, I want to:
 1. Remove the comma (,) between the last and first names of authors.
 2. Switch the sequence of volume, number and year as: year; volume(number):

For example, in the picture Reference[3]: 56.7 (2013) should be 2013; 56(7):

Many thanks.

The following are my `.tex` and `.bib` files:

#### `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sortcites=true,maxbibnames=100,firstinits=true,terseinits=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\intitlepunct}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book, article, thesis, inproceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article} {} {\printtext{\bibstring{in} \intitlepunct}}}


\begin{document}

This is an example for illustration of customizing bibliography style.~\cite{gams,AIChE,Azeez2013}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

#### `.bib` file

```
@article{Azeez2013,
    author = {Azeez, O. S. and Isafiade, A. J. and Fraser, D. M.},
    title = {Supply-based superstructure synthesis of heat and mass exchange networks},
    journal = {Computers \& Chemical Engineering},
    volume = {56},
    number = {7},
    pages = {184--201},
    year = {2013}
}

@book{gams,
    author = {Rosenthal, Racd Ejijig},
    title = {GAMS---A User's Guide},
    year = {2010},
    publisher = {GAMS Development Corporation}
}

@inproceedings{AIChE,
    author = {Savelski, Minor J and Bagajewicz, Michel J},
    title = {Design and retrofit of water utilization systems in refineries and process plants},
    booktitle = {Annual National AIChE Meeting},
    year = {1997},
    location = {Los Angeles, USA}
}
```

Comment: what is the special in the output desired?

Comment: Normally it is preferred to ask one question at a time. Many components of your question have already been answered elsewhere. A good start is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). This `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}` already does some of the things you asked for.

Comment: It would also be really helpful if you could state what exactly you want changed. (I find it quite hard to see the pattern  with the semicolon). But please conduct a search of this site first for each of the items.

Comment: @moewe I edited my problem to make it clearer. Thanks, moewe. I am now reading the materials you offered. I hope I could solve the problem.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the `pp` maybe see [my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195892/line-breaks-in-bibliography-with-biblatex-biber) on avoiding a side-effect. (Also implicitly explains how to get rid of it.) Especially if you might want to specify non-default pagination still. I also [asked about `in`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175730/proper-use-of-in-intitlepunct-for-inbook-entries-in-biblatex?s=3|4.5939).

Comment: Now, I think you'll find that the code in my first comment above answers (1) and (2). For (3), please refer to the very well known [Suppress “In:” biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864) (incidentally, googling for "biblatex in" brings that post up as the first result). (5) Can be dealt with either by `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}` or by the code given in cfr's link above.

Comment: In your new picture I note you got rid of the semicolons was that intended? In your question, however, you still ask for "year;volume" (with a semicolon and without space ...).

Comment: Seeing that all points except for the modifications of the `@article` have been answered, I suggest you make this question about these specific modifications you want applied to `@article`s.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, moewe. I have revised the question specific for article modification.

Comment: The first question could be solved by adding: \renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary modifications for `@article` to look as you wish are as follows

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}
```

To change the order of the fields: first year, only then volume and number.

Then

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

To typeset volume and number as "56(3)".

And finally

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}
```

To make sure the date is not wrapped in parentheses.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sortcites=true,maxbibnames=100,firstinits=true,terseinits=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Azeez2013,
    author = {Azeez, O. S. and Isafiade, A. J. and Fraser, D. M.},
    title = {Supply-based superstructure synthesis of heat and mass exchange networks},
    journal = {Computers \& Chemical Engineering},
    volume = {56},
    number = {7},
    pages = {184--201},
    year = {2013}
}

@book{gams,
    author = {Rosenthal, Racd Ejijig},
    title = {GAMS---A User's Guide},
    year = {2010},
    publisher = {GAMS Development Corporation}
}

@inproceedings{AIChE,
    author = {Savelski, Minor J and Bagajewicz, Michel J},
    title = {Design and retrofit of water utilization systems in refineries and process plants},
    booktitle = {Annual National AIChE Meeting},
    year = {1997},
    location = {Los Angeles, USA}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\intitlepunct}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book, article, thesis, inproceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article} {} {\printtext{\bibstring{in} \intitlepunct}}}


\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \iffieldundef{issue}
    {\usebibmacro{date}}
    {\printfield{issue}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}

This is an example for illustration of customizing bibliography style.~\cite{gams,AIChE,Azeez2013}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Azeez, OS, Isafiade, AJ, Fraser, DM. Supply-based superstructure synthesis of heat and mass exchange networks. Computers & Chemical Engineering 2013; 56(7): 184–201.]

Comment: Can you change the title of the question to a more specific one?

Comment: @Johannes_B Mhh, can you think of a good title?

Comment: :-D No, that's why i asked you :-) It is hard as this is a multi-question Q.

Comment: @Johannes_B So it's a stand-off, then. All I could come up with would be something like: *Change the order of `volume`, `number` and `year` in Articles*, but that is neither catchy nor a very good description of the problem...

Comment: Maybe finding a good duplicate?

Comment: by the way: Many thanks for helping out on golatex :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm not sure whether there is an exact duplicate, though parts of the answer will be scattered throughout other questions on this site (the "volume(number)" thing surely has more than one solution here, I wouldn't expect that for the semicolon though, and the year probably has been moved to all kinds of places).

Comment: Then i'd say the semicolon deal stands out and should go to the title :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Good analysis `:-)`! Maybe *Swap year and volume and separate them by semicolon for Articles* is a cumbersome but more or less accurate title?

Comment: That seems to be fine :-) Go for it.

Comment: @moewe Where could I find the macro code of "journal+issuetitle", "volume+number+eid" and "issue+date". Having these codes, I may do some modification to get my desired bibliography style. Thanks.

Comment: Most of these macros are in `standard.bbx`, but some are in `biblatex.def`. Other still (that are more style-dependent) can be found in the `.bbx` and `.cbx` files of your style, in your case `numeric-comp.bbx`/`numeric-comp.cbx`. If you don't know where to find these files, type `kpsewhich <file>` in your command line and the command line will tell you where the file resides. Keep in mind that you should never modify a file you got from your TeX distribution, with `biblatex` it suffices to make the adjustments in the preamble.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, moewe. Have found the "journal+issuetitle", "volume+number+eid" and "issue+date" definition in standard.bbx and biblatex.def files. They are helpful for customizing bibliography style.

Comment: @moewe I want to put the codes for customizing bibliography style in other files, such as biblatex.cfg, as mentioned here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles], load this style file in my .tex file. How could I achieve that? Many thanks.

Comment: As far as I know you can just create a `biblatex.cfg` where LaTeX can find it and add your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26540/discussion-between-nick-and-moewe).