# Disable microtype for a single paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, microtype

I have the following sequence of lines:

```
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.
```

In case `microtype` is enabled the last line turns out wrong.

[image]

The problem seems similar to [**this one**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285234/disable-protrusion-from-microtype-for-just-one-word) or [**this one**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/disable-microtype-for-a-portion-of-a-document). However the provided solutions do not work for my case. Do you have another solution?

Of course I could just use a tabular environment or similar, but these really wouldn't be handy in this case. How could I just disable microtype for this paragraph?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\microtypesetup{disable} % does not work
\microtypesetup{activate=false,protrusion=false} % does not work
\noindent 
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try it with an explicit `\par` at the end: ``... not required. \par \endgroup``.

Comment: That works, note that it requires either `\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}` or `\microtypesetup{activate=false}`. `\microtypesetup{disable}` does still not work. Maybe you want to make that an answer, with an explanation?

Comment: The microtype documentation allows to disable microtype for a paragraph by simply clicking on a button (this is compatible only with recent viewers). I thought looking [at the source](http://mirrors.xmu.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.dtx) would be of some help, but I just can't understand them. Maybe someone else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The protrusion extension applies to the entire paragraph. In your MWE, you terminate the paragraph after the `\endgroup` where `\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}` is restored again.  Terminate the paragraph within the group:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\microtypesetup{activate=false}
\noindent 
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\par
\endgroup

\bigskip

\begingroup
\microtypesetup{activate=false}
\noindent
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.\\
something is\hfill not required.

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image]

`\microtypesetup{disable}` seems to be an undocumented feature, I haven't tried it.